# PostgreSQL 9.4.5: Limit number of results on INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, join, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement a many-to-many relationship using PostgreSQL's `Array` type, because it scales better for my use case than a join table would.  I have two tables: `table1` and `table2`.  `table1` is the parent in the relationship, having the column `child_ids bigint[] default array[]::bigint[]`.  A single row in `table1` can have upwards of tens of thousands of references to `table2` in the `table1.child_ids` column, therefore I want to try to limit the amount returned by my query to a maximum of 10.  How would I structure this query?

My query to dereference the child ids is `SELECT *, json_agg(table2.*) as children FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2 = ANY(table1.child_ids)`.  I don't see a way I could set a limit without limiting the entire response as a whole.  Is there a way to either limit this INNER JOIN, or at least utilize a subquery to that I can use `LIMIT` to restrict the amount of results from `table2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have been dead simple with properly normalized tables, but here goes with arrays:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1, LATERAL (
  SELECT json_agg(*) AS children
  FROM table2
  WHERE id = ANY (t1.child_ids)
  LIMIT 10) t2;
```

Of course, you have no influence over which 10 rows per `id` of `table2` will be selected.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to use LATERAL in knex?

Comment: I don't know knex so I couldn't help you here. Maybe a new question?